# pipe to less -S without clearing the output from the command line history

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, terminal

so I want to alow horizontal scrolling in the terminal for my custom bash command by piping the output of the command to `| less -S`

However, if I do this, once you exit less, the output of the command will not stay in the command line history

Is there a way to configure less to keep the output of the command in the history when you exit less?

Eg. if you look at `git diff`, you can perform horizontal scrolling and then exit but the output still stays in the history in which you can then type new commands...I essentially want to emulate this for my custom bash command. Also in `git diff` it performs horizontal scrolling on the spot (ie. without using a new screen) and the command line history is still visible whereas for `less` it would do it in its own screen and you won't be able to see the command line history while "lessing". Would it be possible to emulate this git diff-like mechanism in less as well?

If there's any other solution without using `less` feel free to throw it out there

### UPDATED QUESTION

So suppose I do this:

```
cat loremipsum | less -FRSX

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam sed
```

And then I press right twice so that it scroll to the right twice. And then I press q to exit less. The output that remains on the screen will then be:

```
cat loremipsum | less -FRSX
    
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam sed 

 ESCOC

dictum diam. Nullam quis urna ullamcorper, accumsan quam vitae, aliquet 

 ESCOD

nisl. Maecenas vitae lorem orci. Ut vel est erat. Cras quis sagittis sapien, ac volutpat metus. 

 username@server:~/httpdocs$
```

However in git diff when you do the same and then press q, only the last part (ie the last part of the screen where I scrolled to the right)

```
 git diff

nisl. Maecenas vitae lorem orci. Ut vel est erat. Cras quis sagittis sapien, ac volutpat metus. 

 username@server:~/httpdocs$
```

Will remain on the screen

How do I get this to happen as well

Comment: "output" doesn't ever go into the command line history.  Do you mean the in the terminal's dislay/scrollback buffer?

Comment: @Kevin - does `more` support horizontal scrolling, which is being asked for here?  If so, I can't figure out how to enable it.

Comment: @pillarOfLight - Consider editing the question to clarify whether you really mean "command line history" or "scrollback buffer".  hint - if you do, you'll get my upvote :)

Comment: @DigitalTrauma I missed the horizontal part. No, I don't think it does.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't have access to anything I can run `git diff` on right now, but if I read your question and comments correctly, I think the -X option to less would help. e.g.

```
ls -la | less -SX
```

This prevents less from saving and clearing the screen before displaying the output, and clearing and restoring the screen when it quits.

**Update**

I pulled a git workspace and figured out what `git diff` is actually doing:

```
$ pstree -p | grep git
        |-xterm(6021)---bash(6023)---sh(6104)---git(17708)---less(17709)
$ cat /proc/17709/cmdline | xargs -0 echo
less
$ cat /proc/17709/environ | xargs -0 --replace echo {} | grep LESS
LESSOPEN=|/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
LESS=FRSX
$
```

So `git diff` passes no options to `less`.  Instead it is setting the `LESS` environment variable to `FRSX`.  This is the same as passing the -FRSX options to less.  So, do you get what you need with -FRSX:

```
ls -la | less -FRSX
```

Comment: the thing about that is that if you perform horizontal scrolling (press right etc) it will ALSO not clear all outputs of the horizontal scroll hence if you scroll right 2 times the output will stay there 3 times in which the other 2 times will be the output when you scroll right...is there a way to have only ONE output stay there instead of having all scrolled outputs stay there multiple times

Comment: @pillarOfLight - Its not entirely clear what your comment is saying, but I get that -SX is not working for you.  So I dug a little deeper - see my updated answer.

Comment: I looked at your updated question.  As far as I can tell on my system the behavior is identical for `git diff` and `less -FRSX`.  In both cases characters 1-80 of page 1's lines are initially displayed.  if I hit space, then characters 1-80 of page 2's lines are displayed, then if I hit RIGHTARROW, characters 41-120 of page 2 are displayed.  Then if I hit q and scroll up though the scrollback buffer, I see chars 1-80 of page 1 followed by chars 41-120 of page 2.  Is this the behavior you're looking for?  I'm still not 100% getting the difference between your required and observed behavior.

Comment: yeah nvm git diff does the same thing....is it possible to make it so that only the first part of the file remains though (ie. the part that gets displayed prior to to scrolling right)

Comment: or at least make it so that the last part that gets displayed is the first part (eg perhaps bind the resetting to the first part with the "quit" action)

Comment: So if I understand you correctly it sounds like when you hit q, you want chars 1-80 of the current page to be displayed, regardless of which horizontal position the current page is in.  Is that correct?  If so, then it looks like you may be able to set up a key binding with the `lesskey` program.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the command line history, it's the scrollback buffer of your terminal emulator.

Commands that use curses or ncurses typically use escape sequences that save and restore the terminal's state on startup on exit. On startup, a sequence switches to a secondary display buffer, where the command displays all its output. On exit, another sequence switches back to the primary buffer and restores the cursor position. This lets you edit or view a file and then still see your shell command history when you're done.

One workaround is to invoke `less` (or `vim`, or whatever) in another window, which you can leave running while still running commands in your shell. If you use `xterm`, for example, you can type something like:

```
command > command.log ; xterm -e less -S command.log
```

which is easily wrapped in a function or script. If you're not in a GUI environment, `screen` can do something very similar.

Another option, if you want the output of `less` to remain in your current window after you quit (which will scroll your shell command history off the top of the screen) is to use a `terminfo` definition that doesn't define those character sequences. The terminfo capability names are `tmcup` and `rmcup`. You may be able to configure your terminal emulator to disable these capabilities; see the `titeInhibit` resource for `xterm`, for example.

(There *should* be an easier way to do this, but I haven't found it.)

**UPDATE :**

As [DigitalTrauma's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19300861/827263) points out, the `-X` (or `--no-init`) option to `less` inhibits the termcap/terminfo initialization and deinitialization strings (`ti`/`te` in termcap, `smcup`/`rmcup` in terminfo). Either adding `-X` to the `less` command-line options, or adding `X` to the `$LESS` environment variable, should do the trick.

Note that this applies only to `less`. Other full-screen commands, such as text editors, will still save and restore the screen by default. Using the `titeInhibit` resource for `xterm`, or hacking  your `termcap` or `terminfo` entry to remove those escape sequences, will provide a more general solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
export LESS=X # it might be what you are looking for
```